# Two factored polynomials and a parameter

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to solve $p(x)=aq(x)$ with multiple real $a$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the two polynomials in $x$ (with real coefficients).
The roots of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ were found previously, i.e. these two polynomials are factored.

Is it somehow possible to solve the equation in question without multiplying $q(x)$ by $a$ and transferring everything to the left for every new $a$? Is there any workaround?

It's quite frustrating that the two polynomials  $p(x)$ and $q(x)$  are known (together with their roots), but every time I substitute a new parameter value ($a$ in this case) I need to solve a totally new polynomial.

Sorry if the question is stupid. Actually I don't really believe that there's any workaround, although finding one would be really nice.

The problem is solved numerically, all polynomial roots are found as eigenvalues of the polynomial's companion matrix.

Comment: Sketching the zeroes' trajectories of the polynomial $p(x)-aq(x)$ could be possible using the technique called [root locus](http://www.atp.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/rt1/syscontrol/node48.html), which is well known to control engineers. Unfortunately, it doesn't give explicit solutions for $a$, it "only" shows how the roots vary for $a\in [0,\,+\infty)$. Some mild restrictions on  $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ also apply due to the nature of the problem (i.e. control systems).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly no. If there was such a shortcut, solving any polynomial equation would be trivial. For particular forms of your polynomials it might be possible, but not in general.